# Regular Expression - detecting duplicates

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a dataset with the following kind of data:

```
company_id, company_name, country
1, a Tech, germany
2, a Tech AG, germany
3, a Tech gmbh, germany
4, AF, germany
5, AF gmbh, vermany
```

I have already assigned company_id's to these companies based on a preliminary search that assigned ID's to exact matches.  Now, I want to do the following:

1) Write a regular expression that finds if a company name is exactly the same as the    company name below it, except that the second company name has the suffix "gmbh" at the end  of it.

I have everything done except for the logic behind getting the regular expression right. For example:

```
    for next_row in reader:
        first_name = first_row['company_name']
        next_name = next_row['company_name']

        if first_name == next_name:##FIX ME
            #do stuff
        writer.writerow(first_row)
        first_row = next_row
```

The logic for the equality test shouldn't be if first_name == next_name-- but rather if first_name equals last_name plus gmbh...

Would greatly appreciate any clarification!

Comment: `next_name == first_name + ' gmbh'`?

Comment: Have you tried comparing `first_name` to `(next_name + 'gmbh')`?

Comment: is this homework? since you say regex ... but there is no need for a regex for this?

Comment: @Eric, my fault for using a bad example. If next_name equaled first_name plus gmbh most of the time it would be good. But more common is something like this: company 1: aBeg AG. company 2: aBeg GmbH.  Is there an easy way to subtract the "AG"? I can't assume that there is only one word before the whitespace before AG because sometimes there are 2,3 or more words before AG...

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Do you want the condition to return true for `aBeg AG` followed by `aBeg GmbH`?

Comment: Do you have a list of allowable suffixes?

Comment: The most common ones I have observed in the data are: ltd vs ltd., AG vs GmbH, ""(blank) vs GmBH.  I'm sure I'll find others but these are the major ones

Comment: FYI I think I got something that's good enough for my current purposes. It's the following line within the iterator: if (first_name == next_name and next_name + ' GmbH' == full_next_name) or (first_name == next_name and full_first_name[:-4] == full_next_name[:-4])...(where first name and next name are just the first word of each company name before the first whitespace, and full_first_name and full_next_name are the full company names...)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like

```
import re
regx = "([\w\s]+).*\1\s*gmbh"
re.findall(regx,my_target_text,re.MULTILINE)
```

something like that anyway (I think \1 captures first paren in regex ... but that part may be wrong)

also this sounds kinda like homework since you are asking about using regex but there is not much need to use regex

[edit/note]  this is in no way a complete implementation and may require significant tweaking of the regex ... (but it will be simillar)

Comment: Not homework. For work, helping me avoid a lot of manual unpleasantness removing duplicates. regex doesn't matter here, but interesting to see how to use regex in python. I've used it in R before which is easy, but haven't had the chance to do it in Python yet. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm

1. Search for the regex `(.*?)(\s+AG)?` in the `first_name` string and replace it with the `\1`. This will give you company name without `AG`.
2. Assign result to `first_name_without_AG`, then do this: `next_name == first_name_without_AG + ' gmbh'`

### Sample Implementation

```
import re
first_name_without_AG = re.sub("(.*?)(\\s+AG)?", "\\1", first_name)
next_name == first_name_without_AG + ' gmbh'
```

Answer (score 1):

his example has both AG and gmhb?

why not try something like this.

```
for next_row in reader:
    first_name = first_row['company_name']
    next_name = next_row['company_name']
    checkLength = len(first_name)

    if first_name == next_name[:checkLength] :  ##FIX ME
        #do stuff
    writer.writerow(first_row)
    first_row = next_row
```

This only checks the length of the first name brought in and the suffix is ignored in the check.

Comment: Thanks man. In one of my comments above, I ended up finding something just like this, too.